# 4-pin-momentary button replacement with 2N2222A

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches

I want to replace the switch with an arduino trigger. this is my attempt with a 2n2222a, but somehow it triggers the switch not with the HIGHs of the PWM but with a completely other frequency I can't track.

[image] [image]

Comment: Please add a schematic of how you connected your transistors and what was driving them. It's much easier for us to understand a schematic than your written description of the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

The main IC in your Velleman kit is the HT8950, a voice-changer audio effects circuit, from Holtek. I would download the spec sheet and study that. In particular, you want to learn about those 4 control input pins (VIB, TGU, TGD, ROB). What kind of signal do they require? 
I think they may be "toggle" inputs. That means, you only need to send them a short pulse to activate or deactivate the effect.
BTW the 2N2222's base threshold is only 0.6 volts (like all BJTs). You need a series resistor to limit the current, like 10,000 ohms (brown-black-orange).

Comment: how is this threshold named in the data sheet?(http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/a0/75/d9/bd/fc/ca/42/15/CD00003223.pdf/files/CD00003223.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00003223.pdf)

Comment: and please have a look at the schematic I added above. I added also a 10k resistor once but I guess the main mistake is somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

It takes very little to trigger this. The transistor is acting as a switch for a logic level input. No significant current is needed for this to happen, so the quickest pulse of the GPIO is enough. It is not meant to be used as a PWM trigger. It's either on or off, no in between.

Additionally, the pin may be floating at some points in the arduino's startup. A simple pull down resistor at the base would help prevent random triggering.

Also you need to connect the grounds of the Arduino and Voice Changer together otherwise you will see many problems.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you basically have the right idea.  1 kΩ is very low for a base resistor, but won't keep this circuit from working.  10 kΩ would draw less current from the digital output, but should still turn on the transistor to act like a pushbutton plenty well enough.

The only possible problem I see in what you show us is that the transistor is being driven by a PWM output.  The datasheet of the chip shows just a pushbutton connected to ground without anything more.  That means the chip must be doing debouncing internally.  If you try to toggle the transistor too fast, the results will be unpredictable.

Since the chip is meant to respond to pushbuttons on a human scale, it may also take some time to react to whatever it is supposed to do in response to a button press.

For both these reasons, try very slow pulses for starters.  Most debouncing works in 50 ms or less, since that's about the limit of a human noticing a delay.  However, to make sure you aren't pushing any limits, start out with a minimum of 250 ms in both the up and down states before changing any state.  Once you get that working, you can experiment on tightening up the time if you really need faster overall response.  With 250 ms per state, you won't run into any debouncing problems, so you can debug the rest of your circuit.

You show only a single connection between the microcontroller and the transistor switch circuit.  You do have the grounds of the two circuits tied together, right?  If not, that's definitely a problem.